# What do I need to know when picking pet friendly deicers?

Tags: winter

I know that rock salt is inexpensive but can be like little knives on bare paws.  I know some of the special formulas can be more toxic to pets.  What do I need to know when picking pet friendly deicers?

Our pets don't go out in the winter, so paw damage is low on our list.  Larger concerns are consuming any that might get tracked in by people and residual effects to the out doors in the spring.

If you consume enough of anything it is harmful. We keep our deicers where the pets can't reach it.  So primary concerns are for incidental consumption, like licking tracked in salt off of the floor.

Answer (score 3):

There is a product called [Safe Paw](https://www.safepaw.com/) that is made for pets and kids. A de-icer that is pet safe will have a claim on the bag.

I wouldn't worry about your pets eating it, I've never seen a toxicity relating to this and I live in a very ice heavy province so it's (rock salt) used everywhere 24/7. Still a good idea to keep it away from them but you don't need to be concerned about remnants in your house from people coming in.